# Unable to open home page of sidenav

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I am using angular material design for making a website where I am unable to open home of side-bar. Please suggest me any solution.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/webkotactechsan-akntkf

used angular material design

```
     <mat-nav-list>
         <mat-card class="sidemenu">
          <mat-list-item routerLink="home" routerLinkActive="active" >
          <button mat-mini-fab color="primary" aria-label="Example icon- 
   button">
           <mat-icon>home</mat-icon>
           </button>
           <span class="title"><b>Home</b></span> 

          </mat-list-item>
         </mat-card>
```

unable to open home of side-bar

Answer (score 1):

changes you need to do

1. change class name to `export class HomeComponent` in `home.component.ts`
2. spelling of `home.component.scss` is wrong, please correct it.
3. app.module.ts

   ```
   import 'hammerjs';
   import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
   import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
   import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
   import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
   import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

   import { AppMaterialModule } from './app.material.module';
   import { AppComponent, DialogContentComponent } from './app.component';
   import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component'

   const appRoute: Routes = [
   { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent }
   ];

   @NgModule({
     imports: [
       BrowserModule,
       FormsModule,
       AppMaterialModule,
       BrowserAnimationsModule,
       RouterModule.forRoot(appRoute)
     ],
     declarations: [AppComponent, DialogContentComponent, HomeComponent],
     entryComponents: [DialogContentComponent],
     bootstrap: [AppComponent]
   })
   export class AppModule { }
   ```

Changes I did in this file.

a) - added `import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';`
b) - added `import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component'`
c) -

```
const appRoute: Routes = [
{ path: 'home', component: HomeComponent }
]
```

;

d) - added `RouterModule.forRoot(appRoute)`.
e) - added `HomeComponent` in `declarations`.

4. Then add `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in your app.component.html.

Let me know if you have any doubt.

Comment: please check this wokring code `https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8vqpnr`. On click on home close menu and see bottom of page.

Comment: but I have to open in new page not in same page

Comment: I have updated it. Check ur - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8vqpnr

Answer (score 0):

Please add routes in AppModule

```
 RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },

    ],{onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'}),
```

Answer (score 0):

Live Example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/webkotactechsan-q3qjts)

There is something you need to do to solve this problem and implement some angular way to manage components

**1. Implement routing**: The reason behind it, when you click on home, you need to go some router. So, we implement routing to solve this problem.

> ```
> const appRoute: Routes = [
> { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'home'},
> { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
> { path: 'birthday', component: BirthdayComponent}
> ];
> ```

In the above code, we took two components for example purpose. When we call that route, it loads that component. For example we go `home` route it loads home component.

**2. Divide into components**: We are implementing single page application. So, we don't need to copy and paste all the `sidenav`, `topbar` in all components.
We kept those `sidenav` and `topbar` in app components and load `app-content` into `router-outlet`. you can see your inside codes of `app-component` in home and birthday component.

```
  <div class="app-content">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
```

3. Change `routerLink` to home and birthday, so that we need to show home, it loads home components and when we need to show birthday, it loads birthday component.

and finally thanks to [piyush jain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3725110/piyush-jain) for solving common mistakes of your code.